# Cannot connect to Mysql server trough ODBC in php

Tags: php

I tried different ways but I can't a warning saying this:

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a)
>   Driver][mysqld-5.6.17]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ')' at line 1, SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in
>   F:\wamp\www\panier.php on line 30

I get my message Error from sql, just can't see the problem why I can't connect to my database.
I use it in another page and I connect just find

```
$conn=odbc_connect('magasin','','');
    if (!$conn)
    {
        exit("Connection Failed:" . $conn);
    }

$sql= "SELECT ProduitsID,NomProduit,PrixUnitaire,Quantite FROM produits WHERE ProduitsID in" . $ListeProduitID;
//$sql="SELECT * FROM produits WHERE ProduitsID in".$ListeProduitID;
(line 30)$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

if (!$rs)
{
    exit("Error in SQL");
}
```

Comment: Bobby Tables awaits his next victim... http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a connection issue. Just echo the $sql and you will see that you are missing a space.

```
$sql= "SELECT ProduitsID,NomProduit,PrixUnitaire,Quantite FROM produits WHERE ProduitsID in " . $ListeProduitID;
```

Comment: thanks, but you are meaning the space after in. Still gives me the same error. Just don't see why I get this error.

Comment: Can you post the content of the $sql variable before you execute it?